# FTDI device no output on minicom

Tags: drivers, usb, serial-port

I am having trouble in getting a USB to serial to work on Ubuntu. The device contains a FTDI chip, **2232D** to be specific (I can see it on the board). Device has two serial ports so it lists as `/dev/ttyUSB0` &  `/dev/ttyUSB1`

dmesg wrongly lists this as **2232C**.

```
sudo dmesg
[40872.288998] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[40872.441145] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 5.00
[40872.441150] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[40872.441154] usb 2-2: Product: USB <-> Serial
[40872.441157] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[40872.444701] ftdi_sio 2-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[40872.444783] usb 2-2: Detected FT2232C
[40872.445025] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[40872.447122] ftdi_sio 2-2:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[40872.447203] usb 2-2: Detected FT2232C
[40872.447517] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Diver is loaded fine, i see ftdi_sio

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

# usb-devices    
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#= 10 Spd=12  MxCh= 0                                                                                                                                           
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1                                                                                                                                                
P:  Vendor=0403 ProdID=6001 Rev=05.00        
S:  Manufacturer=FTDI                           
S:  Product=USB <-> Serial      
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=44mA 
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=ftdi_sio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=ftdi_sio

# lsmod | grep ftdi_sio
ftdi_sio               61440  0
usbserial              49152  1 ftdi_sio
```

I am very sure I have configured the port and baud right

```
sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB1 -b 115200
```

Ubuntu details

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Linux ThinkPad 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However this works fine on ARCH.

Comment: Try setting baud rate to 9600 and see if that works.

Comment: No doesn't work, I know the device I am connected works at 115200 baud.

Comment: It's not important that your device works at 115200, if the USB serial port adapter can't keep up. That's why I asked if it works at 9600.

Comment: I am not sure, why would it work with Arch Linux then ?

Comment: Arch (on a different computer, I assume) is not Ubuntu on a ThinkPad. Anyway, to eliminate a possible kernel/software problem, boot to a Ubuntu Live 19.10 DVD/USB, install the driver, and retest. Report back.

Comment: Yes, Ok will check with live image.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I gave up, switched to a BAFO USB to Serial. I am pretty sure it was based on FTDI chip-set too but surprisingly worked fine for me. Again this was all about an year ago, don't have all the details. Moreover not using USB to Serial anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is an old thread, but in case someone comes across the same problem, check the flow control settings in minicom. In mine hardware flow control was turned on which resulted in nothing being transmitted. Just turn it off and everything will be fine!